# Webpack ignores 'browser' field after setting 'target' to 'electron-renderer'

Tags: webpack, electron

I'm using webpack with electron, so I have `target: 'electron-renderer'` in my config.

And here comes the problem:

A dependency [`brace`](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace) `require('w3c-blob')`, and [`w3c-blob`](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/w3c-blob) provide two version, one for browser environment and one for node environment, as you can see there're a field named 'browser' and a field named 'main' in its `package.json`.

I expect Webpack to pack the browser version, but as long as I have `target: 'electron-renderer'` in my config, it packs the node version.

I've tried explicitly specifing `mainFields: ["browser", "module", "main"]` in my `resolve`, but it didn't help.

Is there any way to force webpack to use the 'browser' field for a certain package? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specifing `mainFields: ["browser", "module", "main"]` is the right way to force webpack to use 'browser' field.

The reason why it didn't help is that I mistakenly put 'w3c-blob' in my `externals`, removing it solves the problem.